# Pyglet New Version Display Only Black

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, pyglet

So far I have always used Pyglet with `subclassing window`. In practice like this:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet import *
from pyglet.gl import *

class test(pyglet.window.Window):

    old_set = 1024, 576
    new_set = old_set

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.video_set()

        self.label = pyglet.text.Label("TEST", font_name='Times New Roman', font_size=36, x=0, y=0, anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')

    def video_set(self):
        self.platform = pyglet.window.get_platform()
        self.default_display = self.platform.get_default_display()
        self.default_screen = self.default_display.get_default_screen()

        self.set_size(self.new_set[0], self.new_set[1])
        self.location = self.default_screen.width // 2 - self.new_set[0] // 2, self.default_screen.height // 2 - self.new_set[1] // 2
        self.set_location(self.location[0], self.location[1])

        self.set_caption("Test")

        self.set_fullscreen(False)

    def update(self, dt):
        pass

    def draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.label.draw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = test()
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(t.update, 1 / 120)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Now I updated Pyglet a few days ago and now this script no longer works. By searching, I found that `pyglet.window.get_platform()` is deprecated and `pyglet.canvas.Display()` or `pyglet.canvas.get_display()` should be used instead. So I tested, both as it was said, and as I found in other answers, but in any case I get black screen with nothing displayed. Whether it is a label, a sprite or whatever. So, what am I doing wrong in this new version? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Mind telling me which Pyglet version you're running?

Comment: The version should be 1.4, the new version recently released.

Comment: My error, version is 1.5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I doubt that this code worked before - but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt.
Because in this case I think it's because you forgot `on_` before `draw()`. Try out the code below and see if it works, if that's the case, I was on to something :)

```
import pyglet
from pyglet import *
from pyglet.gl import *

class test(pyglet.window.Window):

    old_set = 1024, 576
    new_set = old_set

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.video_set()

        self.label = pyglet.text.Label("TEST", font_name='Times New Roman', font_size=36, x=0, y=0, anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')

    def video_set(self):
        self.default_display = pyglet.canvas.Display()
        self.default_screen = self.default_display.get_default_screen()

        self.set_size(self.new_set[0], self.new_set[1])
        self.location = self.default_screen.width // 2 - self.new_set[0] // 2, self.default_screen.height // 2 - self.new_set[1] // 2
        self.set_location(self.location[0], self.location[1])

        self.set_caption("Test")

        self.set_fullscreen(False)

    def update(self, dt):
        pass

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.label.draw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = test()
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(t.update, 1 / 120)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: You know when you try something new, you get an error that you don't understand, you only focus on solving it, solving it and you don't realize that in the meantime you did some novice bullshit and how much they show you you would like to be buried under ten meters of earth from the shame you are feeling? Here, now I'm feeling that feeling.

Comment: @BlackFenix06 Haha, I feel you! Been there done that too, just glad we could save some time on your project ;) Gl to ya! :)